# How can I edit a csv in power automate that is in SharePoint?

Tags: csv, sharepoint, power-automate

I want to enter from Power Automate to a folder in SharePoint that has some .csv and be able to edit them, could you guide me on which connectors I would have to use and how would the steps be?

Answer (score 0):

1.First we need to get a trigger, it could be manually or automatically, here I use manually:

[image]

2.Then you could use "get file property" action to get the folder you need:

[image]

Click the dot "..." then you could select the account you want to connect, in the action you could get the file properties(columns value in Document content type).

3.You could also use "get file content" and "update file" to copy the file content.

[image]

4.You could also use "update a row" to directly edit the content in the csv file.

[image]